# firebase.messaging: Cannot read property 'getNotificationPermission_' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im trying to add firebase for webpush in one old project.

There are require.js and also I cant use node. So I copy **firebase app** and **firebase  messaging** from firebase cdn (www.gstatic.com) and import them in project.

But when I call messaging method **requestPermission()** it outputs in console  **Cannot read property 'getNotificationPermission_' of undefined**.

Firebase losing context, but if I change all **this** for explicit context assignment, like **let self = this**, everything works fine.

How should I import firebase for its performance?

Comment: I'm with the same problem, If you find a solution please, share :)

Comment: Check my answer below and GitHub issue https://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty, it may help you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, who faced same problem - I find the with [epmty: scheme in requirejs](https://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty). This GitHub issue may help you https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1569